# How To Remove Duplicate Menu Locations

Tags: functions, menus

I am creating some menus but when I go to the menu dashboard It shows up as "Nice Name" and the 'Menu Name' does anyone know how to prevent this or remove it? I attached photo to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

I add my menu in my function.php like so:

```
add_action('init', 'register_menus');
function register_menus(){
    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menus( 
        array(
            'primary-nav', __( 'Primary Menu'),
            'footer-nav', __( 'Footer Menu')
        ) 
    );
}
```

The I call it in my header file like so:

```
 if(has_nav_menu('primary-nav')){ 
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary-nav',
                'container' => 'nav',

            )
        ); 
    }
```

This has me stumped right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You register an array of four menus.
If you reformat your code, you will see it.

```
[…]
array(
    'primary-nav', 
    __( 'Primary Menu'),
    'footer-nav', 
    __( 'Footer Menu')
); 
[…]
```

Adapt your code to an array with custom keys and you will be fine:

```
[…]
array(
    'primary-nav' => __( 'Primary Menu'),
    'footer-nav' => __( 'Footer Menu')
); 
[…]
```